# Best glue for curved veneer

Tags: wood, woodworking, adhesive, wooden-furniture

I have older wood bedroom furniture whose veneers have come undone.

I'd like to re-glue them with the strongest glue possible that can withstand temperatures of about 40-110 degree Fahrenheit.

The veneers/surface are curved.

There're about 4 long pieces like this that have come undone.

Can I glue them without clamps and possibly use a combination of fast trying and slow drying glue or is there one glue that can handle both? Any technique advice would be appreciated along with specifically what is the best glue to use.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: You might also address whatever is leading to furniture meant for a bedroom having to withstand ambient temperatures of 110° F.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The laminate was presumably installed with contact cement. Unless you completely remove that the only viable solution I'm aware of is... more contact cement.

Since contact cement adheres... on contact, simply apply it per the directions, let it dry, and work the laminate back onto the piece from the bottom, keeping tension toward the top as you go.

Comment: I believe even with contact cement, a surface under tension will require clamps/holding weight till cured.

Comment: Then you don't understand contact cement. It's "cured" before you put the parts together.

Comment: Contact cement is not only the appropriate answer, it's the _only_ answer, even if this piece of laminate is completely removed and replaced with a different one. It is appropriate to use a J-roller (sometimes called a brayer) to smooth the laminate down and ensure that it makes complete contact. Be very aware that once it adheres, it is _NOT_ moving! You want to be sure to smooth it down evenly - _any_  bump will remain. However, since it's still partially attached, the repair work will go very easily, and it's highly unlikely that you'll end up with any glitches in the reglued surface.